# Align Input Field (2 per-line) - VueJS

Tags: css, vue.js, surveyjs

I have an issue with alignement of 4 input text in VueJs.

[image]

My container CSS

```
.step__field-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 520px;
    margin: 40px auto auto;
}
```

My input CSS

```
.input__field {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    max-width: 334px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Please help us.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using some form of a loop you could wrap every two in a div. You can use `%` to check for every even loop. i.e. `0 % 2`

Comment: Post your complete code. A demo using Codesandbox would be useful.

Comment: Below my survey template file

Answer (score 1):

If you want a fixed two input fields per row, the following code will do the trick. And using row/column div is also recommended. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_two_columns.asp) for details.

.step__field-container

```
display: -ms-table;
display: table;
```

.input__field

```
width:50%;
```